# Find duplicate items in string

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I've got a big string of IP addresses in a bash script stored as a variable. 
My question is: How can I verify that all of the IP's in the string appear the same number of times? If this helps at all, the number of times that all of the IP's *should* occur in the string is also stored as a variable.

Here's an example to show you what I mean:

```
String "4.2.2.2 8.8.8.8 4.2.2.2 4.2.2.2 8.8.8.8 8.8.8.8"
```

would be OK

```
String "1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 2.2.2.2"
```

would not be OK because there are 3 instances of `2.2.2.2` and two of `1.1.1.1`

```
String "4.4.4.4 3.3.3.3 2.2.2.2"
```

would be OK because they're all in there once.

Comment: Why first string is okay, All values are echoed 3 times there?

Comment: I tried sorting the string to make a list of IP's in increasing order using `sort`, then checking if the first n IP's in said list were the same using `grep -c`, but it didn't work at all.

Comment: @Shiplu - the first one is OK because each IP appears in the string the same number of times. Similarly, for a string that had 40 instances of the same two IP's, it would be OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s="4.2.2.2 8.8.8.8 4.2.2.2 4.2.2.2 8.8.8.8 8.8.8.8"
n=`echo $s | tr " " "\n" | wc -l`
nuniq=`echo $s | tr " " "\n" | sort | uniq | wc -l`
[ $n -eq $nuniq ] || echo "we've got duplicates"
```

or

```
echo $s | tr " " "\n" | sort | uniq -c | grep -qv '^ *1 ' && echo "duplicates!"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to do this with bash and awk:

```
(for ip in $string; do echo $ip; done) | sort | uniq -c | awk 'BEGIN{badString=0}; $1!=1{badString=1} END{if(badString == 1) { print "This was a bad string!"}}'
```

In words:  split each IP in the string into distinct lines, sort them, check to see if the list is unique by counting the occurrences of each IP address, then print "This was a bad string" if any count is not one.

I only did it this way because you tagged with "bash" and "shell," but there exist much simpler perl one-liners to do this :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
$ STR="4.2.2.2 8.8.8.8 4.2.2.2 4.2.2.2 8.8.8.8 8.8.8.8"
$ echo $STR | tr " " "\n" | sort | uniq -c | grep -v " 1 "
   3 4.2.2.2
   3 8.8.8.8
$ STR="4.4.4.4 3.3.3.3 2.2.2.2"
$ echo $STR | tr " " "\n" | sort | uniq -c | grep -v " 1 "
$
```

(no output => OK, with output => Not OK).

or

```
$ STR="4.2.2.2 8.8.8.8 4.2.2.2 4.2.2.2 8.8.8.8 8.8.8.8"
$ ISOK=`echo $STR | tr " " "\n" | sort | uniq -c | grep -v " 1 "`
$ if [[ -z $ISOK ]]; then echo "Is OK"; fi
$
```